# Run 'kubectl' commands from my localhost to GKE - but via tunnelling through a bastion host

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubectl, bastion-host

Currently...

I have a GKE/kubernetes/k8s cluster in GCP. I have a bastion host (Compute Engine VM Instance) in GCP. I have allowlisted my bastion host's IP in the GKE cluster's **Master authorized networks** section. Hence, in order to run `kubectl` commands to my GKE, I first need to SSH into my bastion host by running the `gcloud beta compute ssh` command; then I run the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command to authenticate with GKE, then from there I can run `kubectl` commands like usual.

---

Later...

I want to be able to run kubectl commands to my GKE cluster directly from my local development CLI. In order to do that, I can add my local development machine IP as an allowlisted entry into my GKE's **Master authorized networks**, and that should be it. Then i can run the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` first and then run `kubectl` commands like usual.

---

However...

I am looking for a way to avoid having to allowlist my local development machine IP. Every time i take my laptop somewhere new, i have to update the allowlist my new IP from there before i can  run the `gcloud container clusters get-credentials` command before running `kubectl` commands.

---

I wonder...

Is there a way to assign a port number in the bastion-host that can be used to invoke kubectl commands to the remote GKE cluster securely? And then, i can just use the `gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel` command (which BTW takes care of all permission issues using Cloud IAM) from my local dev CLI to establish a ssh-tunnel to that specific port number in the bastion host. That way, for the GKE cluster, it is receiving `kubectl` commands from the bastion host (which is already allowlisted in its **Master authorized networks**). But behind the scene, i am authenticating with the bastion host from my local dev CLI (using my glcoud auth credentails) and invoking `kubectl` commands from there securely.

---

Is this possible? Any ideas from anyone?

Comment: This seems like a question better suited for ServerFault or [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will post it there.

Comment: Hello. Have you thought about creating a `VPN` server on your bastion host? Could you share what OS image are you running on your bastion machine?  By `Is there a way to assign a port number in the bastion-host that can be used to invoke kubectl commands to the remote GKE cluster securely?` you mean a `port-forwading`?

Comment: For more reference, there is an answer to this question posted here:  https://serverfault.com/a/1026806/545585

Answer (score 0):

This would help accessing to your secured GKE cluster from localhost

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gke-private-cluster-demo

Once the bastion host is setup with tinyproxy as in the above doc, we can use the below shell functions to quickly enable/disable the bastion host access

```
enable_secure_kubectl() {
  # Aliasing kubectl/helm commands to use local proxy
  alias kubectl="HTTPS_PROXY=localhost:8888 kubectl"
  alias helm="HTTPS_PROXY=localhost:8888 helm"
  # Open SSH tunnel for 1 hour
  gcloud compute ssh my-bastion-host -- -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes -M -S /tmp/sslsock -L8888:127.0.0.1:8888 -f sleep 3600
  # Get kubernetes credentials with internal ip for kube-apiserver in kubeconfig
  gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-gke-cluster --region us-east1 --project myproject --internal-ip
}

disable_secure_kubectl() {
  unalias kubectl
  unalias helm
  ssh -S /tmp/sslsock -O exit my-bastion-host
}
```